# Multiple operations in ON CONFLICT DO...?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to somehow have an additional statement executed in ON CONFLICT (line #5) of the code below. Is it possible?

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a, v)
SELECT a, v FROM t2
ON CONFLICT (a) DO 
   UPDATE SET t1.v = t1.v + EXCLUDED.v
  [INSERT INTO t3 (a, v) VALUES(a, EXCLUDED.v)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible using `ON CONFLICT` action. It supports only those:

```
DO NOTHING
DO UPDATE SET
```

You can read more about its syntax in [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html).

You have 2 alternatives for solving your problem:

1. Create trigger `AFTER UPDATE t1` and try to isolate statements that
   come from this upsert. It can be triggered from statements that
   aren't this upsert, but if you have tight control over what is
   executed and updating **only** `t1.v` happens in this specific case,
   then it should be OK. From trigger you can do your INSERT.
2. Use the old way of [BEGIN .. EXCEPTION ..
   END](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING).
   You are risking with this that concurrent transaction will - for
   example - delete row, change it or invalidate first "check". It
   isn't "thread safe".